# Do vulgarity and linguistic flexibility actually correlate?

Tags: word-usage, offensive-language

Regarding “fuck”, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Fuck&oldid=687670053#Grammar) states:

> [it] has a very flexible role in English grammar, which stems from its vulgarity;
>
> the more vulgar a word is, the greater its linguistic flexibility.

**I wonder if this was true.** (Of course, it was just some user who wrote that.)

However, “fuck” has an impressively versatile applicability—even in other languages. But “cunt”, for instance, is surely even more obscene. And I don’t think it’s anything like “fuck” when it comes to figurative portability.

**Is there some truth in the above quoted statement?** Or does “vulgar” in this case mean “common” instead of “obscene”?

Comment: I think you have to define "flexibility" before you can rationally discuss this.  Being able to curse like a seaman is not necessarily being "flexible".

Comment: @HotLicks: I think most people are familiar with its manifold usage, be it as a noun, a verb, an adjective or an adverb. I think it would be unmannerly for me to produce examples of its linguistic versatility. However, I *could*, if it helps the question and its answers.

Comment: This question seems to be "opinion-based".

Comment: @Rathony: Probably to some point, yet a linguist may disprove an actual correlation. Also, even non-professionals may come up with words to falsify (or verify) the statement. Finally, one could put “There’s no determinable correlation” into objective words.

Comment: If "flexibility" simply means different parts of speech, it seems to me that all that's being said is that the more meaningless a word is, the more ways it can be used.  And ultimately, aside from it's negative, crude connotations and one specific meaning as a verb, "fuck" is meaningless.

Comment: @HotLicks: That’s quite plausible. It would also mean that, regarding the Wikipedia quote, “meaningless” would be more accurate than “vulgar”.

Comment: Note that all the Wikipedia article is doing is expressing the opinion of the author.

Comment: @HotLicks: That’s a misconception since it really doesn’t to that. It strives to be objectively verifiable. That’s why there’s dozens of authors on this article alone. And if there’s not *any* evidence for the above statement to be true, we can immediately remove it on grounds of non-confirmability.

Comment: @dakab - A very nice theory.  If only it were true.

Answer (score 2):

A lot of the versatility is because it is firstly a verb. eg run can become runner, run-out-of, run-down, run in family. While "foot" is a lot more limited.

That might explain why fuck, (or wank or shit) are more widely modified than the names of body parts.  Most of the extra uses of fuck are purely as strengtheners. In fuck-up, fuck-off, clusterfuck, you fucker, completely fucked (but not motherfucker) there is no link to sex.

So I would say that the rudest verb is going be very flexible.